# Elastic net: standardize or normalize

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression, lasso-regression

I am using the scikit learn Elastic net as a model for my predictions. I understand i have to normalize/standardize the data before doing the regularization, as that will impact the end model. I need help understanding which scaler to apply to my data: MinMaxScaler, RobustScaler or StandardScaler.

Should i apply this scaler to my Independent Variables (IV)? Should i do the same for the Dependent Variable (DV)?

I want to be able to interpret the coefficients of the model, and determine which feature (IV) contributes more to the outcome (DV).

Is the recommendation different if i have 2 different DVs and i want to compare the coefficients between the two models (compare IV1 for model predicting DV1, and for model predicting DV2).

Comment: Let elastic net take care of that, set normalize parameter to true. For predictions on new data you  don't have to as the coefficients are rescaled.

Comment: @sramalingam24 I appreciate your response, but it is necessary for me to understand why am i choosing one or the other.

Comment: Then statsexchange is probably a better place for your question or any starter text in ML should have basic explanation

Comment: Should you normalize or not with model params, or do it manually via the scalers you mentioned? The only way you can get answer to those questions is through cross validation. ML is about the ability of a model to generalize to new data. And CV will tell which way is right/better.